# Rhythm - help me finish this phrase...The voice of an angel, the rhythm of a _____________

Tags: comparisons

Please help me finish this phrase, the voice of an angel, the rhythm of a _______________.

Comment: Hello, Lori. Maybe "Song"? This question is likely to be closed soon as [off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), because it cannot be given an objective, concrete answer. Please give some time to taking the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't. Welcome to ELU, cheers!

Comment: You first need to decide if the blank is heavenly like an angel, or earthy like a gun.

Comment: *The rhythm of **a metronome** / **a swiss watch** / **John Bonham**.* I picked John Bonham simply because [Rolling Stones](https://www.rollingstone.com/music/music-lists/100-greatest-drummers-of-all-time-77933/ginger-baker-145671/) ranked him as the best drummer of all time. In short, you need to pick something that is synonymous with amazing rhythm. I guess it also depends on how you define rhythm. I could also have gone with a dance (Fred Astaire) or poetry analogy instead. Without context, it's not possible to pin down. There is no similar idiom with rhythm as there is with voice.